# What do you call a politician that is nice but not smart?

Tags: single-word-requests

Some politicians nowadays are twice as nice but half as smart. Most voters end up choosing the nice guy instead of the brilliant one.

Is there a term to this kind of politician, or any person that has a job that needs to lead a group of people like managers, businessman, etc?

Comment: A blowhard? A nincompoop? A chump?

Comment: The Harry Enfield character 'Tim, nice but dim' comes to mind :)

Comment: If a politician is nice but not smart, that puts him ahead of the vast majority, who are neither smart nor nice.

Comment: I've heard the term `all hat and no cowboy`.

Answer (score 1):

First: You sort of answered your own question. They are called politicians.

For Real: I would recommend 'petty' or 'shallow'.